# Get the operations of a sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

how can I get the operations appearing in a sympy expression? For example, for: `2+x**2+exp(7*x)-log(y)`, I need to get back something like: `["+","**","exp","*","-","log"]`. I see there is a simple way to get the variables, using `.free_symbols`. Is there a simple way for operations, too? I also found this function: `srepr` which returns: `"Add(Pow(Symbol('x'), Integer(2)), exp(Mul(Integer(7), Symbol('x'))), Mul(Integer(-1), log(Symbol('y'))), Integer(2))"`. This contains everything I need, but I am not sure how to extract all the parts I need from there in an efficient way? Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of way to go at this. Here are some demonstrations to get you started:

```
>>> eq
x**2 + exp(7*x) - log(y) + 2
>>> count_ops(eq, visual=True) # expression showing how many of each
2*ADD + EXP + LOG + MUL + POW + SUB
>>> count_ops(eq,visual=True).free_symbols  # Symbols
{ADD, EXP, LOG, MUL, POW, SUB}
>>> [i.name for i in count_ops(eq,visual=True).free_symbols] # strings
[MUL, POW, ADD, LOG, EXP, SUB]

>>> [func_name(i) for i in eq.atoms(Basic)]
[Integer, Symbol, Integer, Mul, Symbol, log, exp, Mul, Add, Pow, NegativeOne]

>>> [func_name(i) for i in eq.atoms(Function)]
[log, exp]
```